# How to add Page Event in VS 2010 Web Developer Express

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Such a simple question but if I want to add run some code in the OnPreRenderComplete Event for a Asp.Net page that inherits from a Master Page using Visual Studio Web Developer Express 2010 how can I do it?
Right clicking on the aspx page to get to properties allows me to select all the web controls in the drop down. Once I select one I can just click on the events tab and click in the event I want to have the empty method added to the .cs and register it for the event. But I don't see an option for Page.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnPreRenderComplete` is a `virtual` method in the `Page` class that can be overridden with the `override` keyword.

```
protected override void OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e) {

    // your code...
    base.OnPreRenderComplete(e);

};
```

Don't forget, like I did, to call the base `class`es implementation...

Answer (score 5):

Not sure whether this feature is available in `Web Developer Express` but in Visual Studio you can add/select page event handler via:

1. Right mouse click on .aspx in solution explorer
2. Open "View Component Designer"
3. From properties windows - select "event" icon (yellow colored icon)
4. Double click on event name or type handler name by hand.

If `AutoEventWireup` page is set to "true" then the aspx page also automatically runs methods ([special naming convention of page events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3bwdsh3.aspx)) when certain events are raised. These names are [Page_Init](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), Page_Load etc.

MSDN LINK : [How to: Create Event Handlers in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w2tb12s.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

actually I just remembered that I asked this very same question a while ago
and someone showed me this rather obscure way of doing it:

- open the page in design view
- right click on the background of the page
- select view component designer
- on the properties page you can now select the lightning bolt
- double click an event name to generate the code